# How to disable Livepatch window on boot?

Tags: 20.04, gdm

I am working on a AWS instance running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My display manager is gdm3.
When I access the instance via xrdp, I see this window:

[image]

I'd like to disable this popup via a bash command. How do I get rid of this window in a non-interactive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this with:

`echo "yes" >> /home/ubuntu/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done`